# Construct a target from results of another target

Tags: makefile

I want to write a Makefile that needs to do 2 things:

1. build files using a tool. The known part of the files is an extension. For example `pkg`
2. upload the built files (one by one) using an uploader

`wildcard` doesn't work for me, because there are no files. I tried `.SECONDEXPANSION`, but also unhappy.

What I tried:

```
build:
    do some work to produce *.pkg files

uploading: build $(addprefix upload-, $(wildcard *.pkg))

upload-%: $*
    run a tool to upload one file
```

Comment: Are you saying, you don't know the prefix of any of the files until after the build step has completed?

Comment: correct. I want to do something like the following bash-script but using make
<code>
#!/bin/bash

do_build() #this step produces *.pkg
for f in $(ls *.pkg); do
    upload(${f})
done
</code>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the build step produces `*.pkg` files but you do not know which ones you can invoke make twice. One time to build and a second time to discover the built `*.pkg` files and upload them. And you can use conditionals to distinguish the 2 make runs:

```
.PHONY: uploading build
.DEFAULT_GOAL := uploading

ifeq ($(STEP),)
build:
    do some work to produce *.pkg files

uploading: build
    $(MAKE) STEP=2
else
PKGS  := $(wildcard *.pkg)
UPKGS := $(addprefix upload-,$(PKGS))
.PHONY: $(UPKGS)

uploading: $(UPKGS)

upload-%:
    run a tool to upload one file ($*)
endif
```

Note: you cannot use `$*` in the list of prerequisites as you show in your example. But it is not needed here.

Comment: yeah, running make twice is simplest. I wanted to do whole work by one shot.

Comment: Using conditionals makes things more complex than necessary and hard to read.  There's no need for it.  Just have the recursion run a different target than the main one.  For example the recipe to `uploading` could be `$(MAKE) real-uploading` then have a target `real-uploading` that depends on the packages.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Could you explain why without .PHONY $(UPKGS) all good, but with it $* doesn't work. Thanks.

Comment: Declaring the `UPKGS` targets as phony mainly avoids that make decides not to build them if, by accident, a file with the same name exists. As you probably don't have files with these names you do not see the difference with or without it. You cannot use `$*` in your list of prerequisites because this automatic variable expands as the empty string when make considers the lists of prerequisites, it takes its value only later. Try to replace `$*` by `%` and you will have a real pattern rule.

Comment: Note that in your case adding a prerequisite to the `upload-XXX.pkg` targets is completely useless. As they are phony (or not phony but there is no file with this name) make will always redo them. And as you do not tell make how to build `XXX.pkg` it cannot use this information anyway. If the file exists when make tries to build `upload-XXX.pkg` everything is fine, else make will stop and tell you that it does not know how to make `XXX.pkg`.